# Что означает редкое слово «нето»?

Tags: запятые, орфография, этимология, лексика, значение-слов

Уважаемые любители и профессионалы русского языка и литературы! Перечитывая замечательные сказы уральского писателя Павла Петровича Бажова, обратил внимание на слово "нето".
Примеры:
**1.** Заходи, нето. Кого первого лобанить?
**2.** Поедем, нето, в дальнюю курейку.
**3.** Получай, нето, да выбирай, какой любее! И т. д.

Обратился к словарям и интернету за помощью в переводе этого слова. И что интересно, его там вообще нет. А есть НЕ ТО (пишется отдельно), обозначающее ИНАЧЕ, ИЛИ, НЕ ТО ЧТО(БЫ). Но это не подходит по смыслу!

В связи с этим вопросы: 1) как у Бажова переводится НЕТО; 2) почему пишется слитно; 3) зачем выделяется запятыми?

Answer (score 3):

В ["Словаре русских народных говоров"](https://iling.spb.ru/dictionaries/srng/21.pdf) (редактор Ф.П. Филин, выпуск 21, 1986 год) есть много примеров употребления этого слова.

1. Нéто (наречие) Едва, насилу, с трудом (Нето баю)
2. Нетó (частица) 1. Будто (Она нето одна в селе в нашей). 2. Хоть, что ли (Сказала нето суседке, что гуси ее на реку пошли)
3. Нетó (наречие) 1. В таком случае, тогда. 2. Как-нибудь, когда-нибудь (Тут как раз пример из Бажова: "Заходи нето").
4. Нетó (вводное слово) Пожалуй (Пойду, нето, я к дедку Ефиму жить)
5. Нéто (вводное слово) Что же, если так (Ну, нето иди, ладно уж)

Comment: Забыл про этот словарь... Хорошо, что нашли! Благодарствую!